# Dynamic 'group by' in ng-options

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got a few selects which I'm populating with ng-options. I'm wondering if it's possible to dynamically group/not group this select.

Here's a (simplfied) `<select>`:

```
<select class="brand-select" 
  ng-model="selectedBrand" chosen="brandList"
  ng-options="brand as brand.name group by brand.bestseller for brand in brandList">
</select>
```

I'd like to be able to switch between that select and this (note, there's no group by in this one):

```
<select class="brand-select"
  ng-model="selectedBrand" chosen="brandList"
  ng-options="brand as brand.name for brand in brandList">
</select>
```

I'd like the grouping to be bound to a $scope variable.

I've tried tying the select to a directive and setting the value of the ng-options attr dynamically, but it seems this isn't possible.

Any suggestions on the best way to do this other than having two selects and showing/hiding one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function to determine "group by" value - return null if no group is needed:

```
$scope.grouping = true
$scope.groupBy = function(v){return $scope.grouping ? v[0]: null}
...
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="k group by groupBy(v) for (k,v) in friends"></select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cWH4n/

Answer (score 3):

While answer from 4vanger above is correct if you're using angular 1.4.8 and below, please note that when using angular 1.5 and above you have to return 'undefined' to disable the grouping. Otherwise a "null" group will appear.

Comment: Saved me some hazzle, had exactly this issue with the example 4vanger mentioned. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there any way to use grouping in ng-options while leaving some elements outside the groups? Simply setting undefined for the group value doesn't work. It hasn't been a problem in angular 1.4.4, an empty string did the trick, but now I get a null group for the element that I want to keep separated.